# Is Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop (Full) Possible in 25G or Lower Hard Disk Space?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, 22.04, minimal-install

Is it Possible to install Ubuntu 22.04 (Full) in 25GB Partition or Lower Space
I tried Ubuntu Minimal Install Option in Installer but seems like it does not installs drivers or work even checked in installer to install drivers , so is it possible to install Ubuntu 22.04 (Full) in 25GB Partition or Lower Space

Comment: Read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Comment: I have been running 22.04 on a 16GB USB testing Daily Build, Beta and Release. There is not a lot of room to install downloaded programs that I don't need or will never use, otherwise it works fine. I used a 32GB drive with 20.04 for a couple years without filling it up.

Comment: Well , looks like ubuntu does not takes much space at-all i dualbooted yesterday and everything seems fine. 25GB and 12GB Space free after installing some programs

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect it to be approximately the same as 20.04;
here is what I see:

```
$ du -sh / 2>/dev/null
100G    /

$ du -sh /home
85G /home

$
```

So the large amount of data is in /home/
Approximately 15G used for OS and (a modest amount of) installed software.
Still, I **do** `apt purge ...` (and related) on software I don't use.

Running nicely on a laptop with i7 with 16G RAM and nVidia 1660i